# How to have 2 jqconsole terminals on the same webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to have 2 [jq-consoles](https://github.com/replit-archive/jq-console) on the same page, but all of the provided css and generated html is all based off id's. If I copy all of the code and change the variable names, nothing works still.